# check whether $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-3)$ is a field or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Find out whether Quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-3)$ is a field? I know that $x-3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ but further don't know.

Comment: You can study maximality of the ideal generated by $x - 3$.

Comment: Trivially different from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1585891/29335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\psi :Z[x]\to S$ is a homomorphic surjection to a ring $S$, with $\ker (\psi)=\{(x-3)f :f\in Z[x]\},$ then $S=\{\psi (n):n\in Z\}$ because $\forall f\in F[x]\;\exists g\in Z[x] \;\exists n\in Z\; (f=n+(x-3)g ).$ Now $\psi (n)\ne 0$ for $n\in Z\backslash \{0\}$ otherwise $n\in \ker (\psi).\;$ And $S$ is not a field,  else for some $n\in Z$ we will have $\psi(1)=\psi (1)\psi (2)\psi (n)=\psi (2n)$, implying $0=\psi (1-2n)\ne 0.$

Answer (score 8):

The ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z[x]\rightarrow \mathbb Z$ given by $x\mapsto 3$ is surjective with kernel $(x-3)$. Hence $\mathbb Z[x]/(x-3) \cong \mathbb Z$, which is not a field.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a field.

You may think that being $x-3$ irreducible, the ideal $(x-3)$ must be maximal and thus $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-3)$ would be a field, since:

> Given a commutative ring $R$ and $I\subset R$ a maximal ideal, $R/I$ is always a field.

Sadly, this is *wrong*. $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a PID, and $f$ irreducible does not imply that $(f)$ is maximal.

In fact, $(x-3)\subsetneq (2,x-3)\subsetneq\mathbb{Z}[x]$, therefore $(x-3)$ cannot be a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

---

Alternatively, you can see that the surjective ring homomorphism
$$\varphi:\mathbb{Z}[x]\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$
$$f(x)\mapsto f(3)$$
gives $\ker\varphi = (x-3)$ and $im\varphi = \mathbb{Z}$, thus $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-3) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$, which is not a field.

Comment: I believe you mean to say that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a PID, but instead you said that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a PID.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Edited